# JMS Message body is null when publishing with jms:publish-subscribe-channel

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

I am trying to use jms:publish-subscribe-channel to pub/sub on a single ActiveMQ topic. I am able to receive messages from ActiveMQ on the channel just fine, however when I publish to the channel the message body is null (when received by another application listening on the ActiveMQ topic). I was able to recreate the problem using spring-integration-samples->basic->jms. I modified outboundChannelAdapter.xml to use jms:publish-subscribe-channel instead of jms:outbound-channel-adapter. Is there another step needed in order to publish a simple string message? Here's my code change to outboundChannelAdapter.xml:

```
<stream:stdin-channel-adapter id="stdin" channel="stdinToJmsoutChannel"/>

<jms:publish-subscribe-channel id="stdinToJmsoutChannel" topic="requestTopic" />    

<stream:stdout-channel-adapter id="stdout" channel="stdinToJmsoutChannel" append-newline="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "the message body is null".

I just made the exact same change to the sample and it worked fine for me...

```
Please type something and hit <enter>

foo
foo
```

I had to add `-Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES=*` to the command line because activemq needs whitelisting for classes (the whole message is serialized in jms-backed channels).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Gary. Is it possible to send the message as a string rather than a serialized object?

Comment: Not with a JMS-backed channel - use a pair of channel adapters for that - the message payload becomes the JMS message body; the headers are mapped to JMS headers (as long as `extract-payload` is true - the default). JMS-backed channels are intended for persistence, not for distributing data to other apps.

Comment: Ok got it. Since I'm using pub/sub on the same topic, how do I avoid receiving the same message I just sent out when using a pair of channel adapters?

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you mean. The outbound adapter publishes to the topic; multiple inbound adapters will each get a copy of the message but each one will only get one. Presumably you're using a topic because you have multiple recipients.

Comment: The behavior I'm seeing--with a pair of channel adapters running in the same service--is that anytime I publish a message on the outbound I see it come in on the inbound. I would like to filter out messages sent by my service. That's why I was looking at publish-subscribe-channel since it handles that.

Comment: I am still having trouble understanding. If you just want to publish a message to some other service(s), why do you have an inbound adapter in this service? Perhaps I am missing something; if so, edit your question to show your configuration (it won't format well in a comment).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It's a distributed system with multiple nodes exchanging xml messages on an ActiveMQ topic. My service needs to both receive messages coming from other nodes and publish messages to them. Since pub and sub are on the same topic, I would like to avoid having the messages I'm sending echo back to me, or filter them out since there's no need for me to deal with them. Hope that helps.

Comment: That's definitely not the purpose of a pub/sub JMS-backed channel. One solution is to have some unique identifier for a node (perhaps a system property); set a message header (e.g. via a `header-enricher`) before publishing. Then, on the inbound adapter, use a message selector in the  `selector` attribute; e.g. `myHeader <> 'thisNodeId'`